# Implementing a log in/sign up feature

Tags: forms, authentication

So i'm an intermediate web designer. I want to make a website that lets students at my university collaborate by advertising work and being able to apply. It's a digital arts university and collaborating is important for everyone.

I want to make the site exclusive to students at my uni, therefore will need a sign up/ log in feature, and I have no idea what I need or how to go about it. I'm guessing databases are required? I have database knowledge, so shouldn't be a problem.

I also want to make the sign up feature exclusive to students with an e-mail domain specific to my uni. I know this is possible, but guessing this would require "verification" e-mails to be sent automatically, which makes things harder.

So what i'm asking, is for some guidance on the matter, if anyone has experience or knows of some good resources I could use, that would be great.
ps. I'm not interested in having "profiles" and pages for each member, just want it as a security feature more than anything.

thanks alot!

Comment: Lewis, Stack Overflow is a forum aimed at solving programming problems and question you ask here is ver *very* broad. Basically you ask how to do a login to secure resources and noone is able to give you a definitive answer to that question because there's a myriad ways to accomplish that. Please try being more specific, for example if you know databases this means you most likely know some programming language - even this distinction would make you question way easier to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really give you a perfect answer without understanding lots more about the environment, but I can point you in the right direction. But, before I start, let me say this:

**Warning:** Users reuse passwords across sites. So, while a password database exposure for your site might not be a major problem (it doesn't sound like you're storing credit card numbers or other sensitive material), you may end up exposing the users at other sites.

Here are some ideas to try in order of easiest (ie: most secure) to hardest (ie: riskiest):

1. Single sign-on (SSO): Most organizations of moderate size have some SSO mechanism in place. This is something that allows your program to ask the user to login to their school account using their school login and password. If the login is successful, you're program will securely be given the email address of the user who just authenticated. You'll need to ask people in your school's IT department about this. Asking them "Do you support an OAUTH, SAML, or similar SSO that I can connect to my application?" should get you started. Odds are that they do have an SSO mechanism but may not let random apps connect to it. You'll need to see. I like this solution best because it gets you out of the authentication business altogether.
2. Use your web framework's authentication system: Many web frameworks support authentication out of the box. For example, if you are using JBoss or .NET, you can leverage their authentication system. You'll need to read up on the framework you're using. I'm pretty sure that PHP does not support authentication out of the box. So if you're using that this option isn't available.
3. Find an authentication library you can leverage: Just start googling around for `open source authentication framework PHP` or whatever framework you're using. If you find one, you'll only need to install and configure it.
4. Write your own: The general strategy is to store a username and a salted hash of the password. [This reference](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) on secure password storage should help.

As a general rule with security, the more you can leverage existing services, the more secure the solution will be. So try to leverage someone else's work before getting creative.